# How to find the closed form of a function that is a probability distribution multiplied by a weighted square error?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, machine-learning

**Question :**
[image]

I'm not sure how to handle the probability distribution when reducing this

Comment: Derivatives may help

Comment: So, I've done a variation of this where it was easy to derive. But with the probability distribution added, I'm stumped on how to handle the 'p' terms.

Comment: So what would you do without the $p_i$ or where they were all a constant $\frac1n$?

Comment: On deriving it and reducing it, I can show that mu equates to the mean of x.

Comment: Each $p_i$ will multiply its bit of the derivative by $p_i$.  Then do as you did before and collect all the $x_i$ terms together and all the $\mu$ terms together

Comment: So, on collecting it, I get (p1x1^2 + p2x2^2 + ..... pnxn^2) + n(mu)^2 -2(mu)(p1x1 + p2x2 + .... + pnxn)

Comment: Okay, I think I got it :) I'm getting a final answer of (mu) = 1/n * mean(x)

Comment: Not quite.  (a) It is not $n\mu^2$ but $(p_1+p_2+\cdots +p_n)\mu^2$ and the bracketed terms do not add up to $n$; (b) you need the derivative of that with respect to $\mu$ and (c) you are doing this in $d$-dimensional space.  You should end up with the weighted mean

Comment: You're right, I derived it again, and I'm getting p1x1 + p2x2 + ... + pnxn/ p1 + p2 + ... + pn. 
Thanks for your help!